# Group numbers in a list in scheme?

Tags: list, split, scheme, racket

When given a list, I have to split the list into lists that group together elements that are the same.

For example: '(37 37 39 38 38 39 38 40 40 38) has to result in '((37 37) (39 39) (38 38 38 38) (40 40))

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The result should be '((37 37) (39 39) (38 38 38 38) (40 40))

Comment: You can use [group-by](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=group#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._group-by%29%29): `(group-by identity '(37 37 39 38 38 39 38 40 40 38))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
(define (group lst)
  (let iter ((lst lst) (found null) (res null))
    (if (null? lst) ; all done ...
        (reverse res) ; ... return result (reversed)
        (let ((c (car lst))) ; isolate first element
          (if (member c found) ; already processed that
              (iter (cdr lst) found res) ; just go on with the next
              (iter (cdr lst) ; otherwise add this to found and create a list of as many elements ...
                    (cons c found) ; ... as found in the list to the current result ...
                    (cons (make-list (count (curry equal? c) lst) c) res))))))) ; ... and go on with the next
```

Testing

```
> (group '(37 37 39 38 38 39 38 40 40 37))
'((37 37 37) (39 39) (38 38 38) (40 40))
> (group '(37 37 39 38 38 39 38 40 40 38))
'((37 37) (39 39) (38 38 38 38) (40 40))
```